# Rail4 - How To Multi-level Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I want to get the values in:

`New` -> `Type` -> `Version`

I Have this setup:

```
class New < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :type
end

class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :new
   has_many :versions
end

class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :type
end
```

How can I access `@new.type.version.first` ?

Thanks!

Comment: beware that `new` is a ruby reserved word and `type` is rails reserved word for STI. your heading into trouble with such naming...

Comment: In fact I'm not using this names on project, its just for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
class New < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions, through: :type
  ...
end
```

@new.versions.first

Comment: Because of the has_many you can just do `@new.versions.first`

Comment: But the form of the version is a field_for inside type form, then when I gonna create a register with the new form I select the type, who already has the version associated.

Comment: When I try @new.versions.first or @new.type.versions.first I get: undefined method `version' for #<News:0x0000000b5f24f8>